# $R$ is a partial order on a set A, and $B ⊆ A$. Prove that if R is a total order and b is a minimal element of B, then b is the smallest element of B

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$, and $B ⊆ A$. Prove that if $R$ is a total order and b is a minimal element of $B$, then $b$ is the smallest element of $B$.

My attempt:

Suppose $R$ is total order.

Since $R$ is total order on $A$, for two arbitrary elements $x \in A$ and $y \in A$, either $(x,y) \in R$ or $(y,x) \in R$.

Since $B \subseteq A$, the same will hold for two arbitrary elements in $B$.

Suppose $b$ is a minimal element of $B$. Take arbitrary $a \in B$ and $a ≠ b$. We know that either $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ must be in $R$. Since $b$ is the minimal element, we know that $(a,b) \notin R$, which implies that $(b,a)$ must be. By definition of the total order, we also know that $(b,b) \in R$. Which implies

$$\forall x \in B(bRx)$$

Therefore, $b$ is the smallest element. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Nitpicking: "Since $b$ is **a** minimal element ..."

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Your proof is correct... It is not difficult at all. For total orders if there is a minimal element it is unique... And of course it must the minimum...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the situation is:  There is a set $A$ in which a partial order $R$ is defined (usually a partial order defined in a set is denoted with the symbol $\preceq$. So instead of writing $R$, I'll follow tradition and write $\preceq$ instead).

Let $B$ be a subset of $A$ and that $\preceq$ totally orders $B$, i.e., $B$ is linearly ordered by $\preceq$ or $B$ is a chain in $A$ with respect to $\preceq$.  Now we are required to show that any minimal element of $B$ is the least element.

Proof.  Let $m$ be a minimal element in $B$.  The element $m$ being a minimal element means that no element of $B$ precedes $m$.  Put another way, **minimality** says that $$x\ \preceq\ m\ \ \mbox{implies}\ \ x\ =\ m\ \ \mbox{for every}\ \ x\ \in\ B.$$ The element $m$ being the least element in $B$ means that $$m\ \preceq\ x\ \ \mbox{for every}\ \ x\ \in\ B.$$Put another way, says that *$m$ is the **smallest element** if no element in $B$ different from $m$ precedes $m$*.

Knowing that $\preceq$ is a total ordering of $B$ i.e., knowing that $B$ has no incomparable elements whatsoever and as such, we must have  $$x\ \preceq\ m\ \ \mbox{for every}\ \ x\ \in\ B\ \ \mbox{OR}\  \  m\ \preceq\ x\ \  \mbox{for every}\ \ x\ \in\ B.$$Looking at the case $x\ \preceq\ m$ for every $x\ \in\ B$ reduces to $x\ =\ m$ for every $x\ \in\ B$ because $m$ is a minimal element, i.e.,intuitively, $m$ is at the bottom in the ordering. Now the total order conditions becomes $$x\ =\ m\ \ \mbox{for every}\ \ x\ \in\ B\  \ \mbox{OR}\ \ m\ \preceq\ x\ \ \mbox{for every}\ \  x\ \in B.$$ Consider these two cases separately, to see that in either case, we have that $$m\ \preceq\ x\ \ \mbox{for every}\ \ x\ \in\ B$$ which says precisely that $m$ is the smallest element in $B$.

Furthermore, a least element in an ordered set is unique.  So we have shown that a totally ordered set which possesses a minimal element, possesses one and only one such element which is the smallest element in that ordered set.

Notice that if our minimal element $m$ was not the first element in $B$, there must be some element, say $y$ in $B$ such that $y\ \prec\ m$ (read as $y$ precedes $m$) and this would clearly contradict the fact that $m$ is minimal in $B$---no element of $B$ whatsoever may precede $m$.